# Cordova, angular and sqlite

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova

### I have using cordova, sqlite and angular. I call this init function in ng-init for html view. This init function not return success data. But this code is correct. my question how to call sqlite fetch data in ng-init function

```
$scope.InsertMydevices = function() {   
    var userdata = CF2018.ETL.getUser();    
        userdata = userdata.UserName;

    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DeviceModel WHERE CreateBy=?', [userdata], function (tx, res) {                
            var len = res.rows.length, i;
            $scope.datalength = len;
            alert($scope.datalength);   
            $scope.$apply();            

        }, null);
    }, function(error) {
        alert(error.message);               
    }, function() {
        alert('datachecked');   
    });

}
```

Comment: Please help...how to solve this ...

Comment: @Arun- you are calling javascript interface of SQLite Cordova plugin from angular right?